# UIScrollview is not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, contentsize

I know there are tens of similar question about scrollview but I have tried everything, `Scrollview` is not scrolling.

First I created a `uiviewcontroller` with a xib file, and set it to freeform and arrange the size of it and added a scrollview on view.

[image]

Then added it as a `childviewcontroller` to another view controller.

```
-(void)scrollViewSetup
{
    if (!_scrollView) {
        _scrollView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,200)];
        [self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

        ScrollView *displayPortf=[[ScrollView alloc] init];
        //add as a child view controller here
        //displayPortf.delegate=(id)self;
        [_scrollView addSubview:displayPortf.view];
        [displayPortf didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self addChildViewController:displayPortf];
    }
}
```

Content size of scroll view is `(768,200)` on iPad.
I tried setting `content size` to `(1920,200)` in `viewDidLoad` didn't work then `viewDidAppear` didn't work then `viewDidLayoutSubviews` didn't work.

Then I checked the `use auto layout` box and tried to add constants by going`editor->resolve auto layout issues->add constraints`

How can I make scrollview to scroll?

Note: Parent view uses auto layout and storyboard.

Comment: You've got too many things called `scroll views`, which makes it difficult for anyone to understand what you are trying to do.  For example, I'm guessing that `_scrollView` is actually the content view. Also the class called `ScrollView` is apparently a UIViewController. If those guesses are correct, then you need to instantiate the view controller first, then add the content view as a subview of the `UIScrollView` that came from the nib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the reason of issue is zero width of `scrollView`.
When you call this:

```
_scrollView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,200)];
```

`_scrollView` is initiated with width `self.scrollView.frame.size.width`, but at this moment `self.scrollView` is nil as it related to instance variable `_scrollView` that hasn't initiated yet.

Try to set some non zero float value for view width:
`_scrollView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,768,200)];`